# How to insert same data into two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Is this possible if I want to insert some data into two tables simultaneously?
But at `table2` I'm just insert selected item, not like `table1` which insert all data.
This the separate query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(model, serial, date, time, qty) VALUES ('star', '0001', '2010-08-23', '13:49:02', '10')";   

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2(model, date, qty) VALUES ('star', '2010-008-23', '10')";
```

Can I insert `COUNT(model)` at table2? 
I have found some script, could I use this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(model, serial, date, time, qty) VALUES ('star', '0001', '2010-08-23', '13:49:02', '10')";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if(isset($model))
{
  $model = mysql_insert_id($conn);
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO table2(model, date, qty) VALUES ('star', '2010-008-23', '10')";   
  $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Why don't you create a View Table for table 2? And just for curious, why do you need these 2 separated tables?

Comment: i mean from that separate codes, can i combine become one command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is no - there is no way to insert data into two tables in one command. Pretty sure your second chuck of script is not what you are looking for.

Generally problems like this are solved by ONE of these methods depending on your exact need:

- Creating a view to represent the second table
- Creating a trigger to do the insert into table2
- Using transactions to ensure that either both inserts are successful or both are rolled back.
- Create a stored procedure that does both inserts.

Hope this helps

Comment: That seems to allow you to do Insert1 OR Insert2 the and I thought you needed both Insert1 AND Insert2

Answer (score 1):

//if you want to insert the same as first table

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO table (one, two, three) VALUES('$one','$two','$three')";

$result = @mysql_query($qry);

$qry2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (one,two, three) VVALUES('$one','$two','$three')";

 $result = @mysql_query($qry2);
```

//or if you want to insert certain parts of table one

```
  $qry = "INSERT INTO table (one, two, three) VALUES('$one','$two','$three')";

  $result = @mysql_query($qry);

  $qry2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (two) VALUES('$two')";

  $result = @mysql_query($qry2);
```

//i know it looks too good to be right, but it works and you can keep adding query's just change the

```
     "$qry"-number and number in @mysql_query($qry"")
```

Answer (score 0):

its cant be done in one statment,

if the tables is create by **innodb** engine , you can use [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) to sure that the data insert to 2 tables

Comment: what's the better solution for this? can i fill the 2nd table after fill the 1st table?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    if($username == NULL OR $password == NULL OR $email == NULL OR $website == NULL) {
        $final_report2.= "ALERT - Please complete all fields!";  
    } else {
        $create_chat_user = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `chat_members` (`id` , `name` , `pass`) VALUES('' , '$username' , '$password')");
        $create_member = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`id`,`username`, `password`, `email`, `website`) VALUES ('','$username','$password','$email','$website')"); 
        $final_report2.="<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=login.php'>";
    }
}
?>
```

you can use something like this. it works.

Comment: Can you please explain why this works and the asker's approach did not?

Answer (score -1):

In general, here's how you post data from one form into two tables:

```
<?php
$dbhost="server_name";
$dbuser="database_user_name";
$dbpass="database_password";
$dbname="database_name";

$con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to the database:' . mysql_error());

$mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (table1id, columnA, columnB) 
         VALUES (' ', '$_POST[columnA value]','$_POST[columnB value]')";

mysql_query($sql);

$lastid=mysql_insert_id();

$sql2=INSERT INTO table2 (table1id, table2id, columnA, columnB)
              VALUES ($lastid, ' ', '$_POST[columnA value]','$_POST[columnB value]')";

//tableid1 & tableid2 are auto-incrementing primary keys 

mysql_query($sql2);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

//this example shows how to insert data from a form into multiples tables, I have not shown any security measures

Comment: is this save? I'm worry i will get some SQL Injection.