# How to have the same data on two different tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to modify an application in PHP, I actually want to add a service to the application. I already have a table Login, I want to create another one called UserLogin, I want the new table UserLogin to have the same data when a query is executed. I want to do this without writing an INSERT statement twice. I want every data that goes into Login to be available in UserLogin too.

Comment: Triggers would help with that, it's configured at the backend.

Comment: Like the comment above mine says, you can achieve that using triggers. However, if you have exact duplicate of a table, one must wonder what's the purpose of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert same data into two tables in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545312/how-to-insert-same-data-into-two-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: If you want UserLogin to have the same data as Login, why don't you just create an Alias? Login As UserLogin

Comment: Ok thanks..the purpose is that, on the UserLogin table I have an extra column, so the table is a bit different in terms of structure.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the column to the Login table?

Comment: @DanBracuk hit the nail on the head, why would you COPY data between two tables if you can have 1 table with that extra column? Don't make your life miserable for no reason.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a view of the first table that does not have the extra column.

Comment: He's looking to add a field, not take one away.

Comment: So add the field to the new table and make the old table a view.  A better answer would be to normalize the data but I figured that would just lead to more questions so make a view with a removed column is a much simpler thing to do to solve the immediate problem.